# Intercept IE Context Menu Click in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am using WinForms, i have added a WebBrowser control and would like to able to intercept a context menu firing event for the IE browser since the browser control is an instance of IE.

I mean, i want to intercept the right click menu item click for the browser it self, i said to my self since it's an IE instance and it's inside my application, there got to be a way to do it.

I tried to look at the events of the browser control, but nothing there is nothing that would help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of canceling WebBrowser context menu. This will help you move on:

```
// wb = WebBrowser control instance name
// attach to the DocumentCompleted event
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // when the document loading is completed, attach to the document context showing event
    wb.Document.ContextMenuShowing += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_ContextMenuShowing);
}

void Document_ContextMenuShowing(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    // cancel showing context menu
    e.ReturnValue = false;
    // take a look at the 'e' parameter for everything else, you can get various information out of it
}
```

Comment: Isn't here anyway, that i could intercept an event in the menu like for example "Send to OneNote"...

Answer (score 0):

Set the below simple property of webbrowser control

```
wbBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
```